# Android location permissions

Tags: android, gps, triangulation, android-permissions

In my **Android** application I'm willing to use **GPS locations**.

1. What are the main **permissions** that I should included in **android
   manifest** file in order to use GPS locations.
2. In case of **lost the GPS signal** strength, is there any way to **triangulate** the position using **mobile networks.**

Thank you!

Comment: Have you at least read: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html and http://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The main permissions you need are `android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` or `android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`.

Only fine location will allow you access to gps data, and allows you access to everything else coarse location gives. You can use the methods of the [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) to acquire location data from gps and cell tower sources already, you do not have to work out this information yourself.

If you are targeting API Level 21 (5.0) or higher, you may also need this:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
```

Answer (score 15):

This permission should allow your app to use location services through the devices GPS, wifi, and cell towers. Just plop it in your manifest wherever you put your permissions, and it should do the trick. You can find all the other permissions here: (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html)

Here is the code:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and noticed that the code was requesting high accuracy but the manifest had course permissions.  I changed it to fine and the error no longer occurs.

Make sure the code and the manifest reflect the same level of accuracy requested and allowed.

So if the manifest has android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION the application can request geolocation.getCurrentLocation({ desiredAccuracy: Accuracy.high...